# Virtual Box for Mac OSX El Capitan

Tags: virtual-machine

Firstly i should mention i own a legal copy of the Mac OSX however i wish to install it on a virtual machine on my windows 10 64bit pc. I downloaded the vmdk file for it, but on every sites guildline the version drop down shows the mac osx el capitan version whereas mine is only showing mac osx 34bit and lac osx snow leopard. 
am i missing something to make it display? the link to the guide im using is:
[link to guide](http://www.wikigain.com/install-mac-os-x-el-capitan-virtualbox/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you may possess a legal copy of OS X, the license agreement only permits you to virtualize it with an Apple-branded computer as the physical host and is running the same OS.

https://ssl.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/OSX1011.pdf (page 2, emphasis mine) speaks to this if you got the OS through the App Store:

> (iii) to install, use and run up to two (2) additional copies or instances of the Apple Software **within virtual operating system environments on each Mac Computer you own or control that is already running the Apple Software**, for purposes of: (a) software development; (b) testing during software development; (c) using OS X Server; or (d) personal, noncommercial
>   use

If you got the OS pre-installed on a Mac, you can't transfer that to a VM (see the section of the agreement above what I pasted) **and** it still requires that you run it on Apple-branded hardware.

Long story short, if you virtualize your legal copy of El Capitan on VMWare running on a Windows PC, you'll be in violation of the license agreement.

Comment: thanks for that, didnt realize that and you worded it out nicely.